# Can Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $C[0,1]$ be generated by compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

We have $X = C([0,1])$ with its sup-norm. Let $\mathcal{B}(X)$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $X$.

My question is can $\mathcal{B}(X)$ be generated by compacts? I think the answer is no but don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arzelà–Ascoli’s theorem implies that any compact subset of X is nowhere dense. In particular the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the compacts is contained in the collection of Borel sets of $X$ that are meagre or co-meagre because the latter collection is a $\sigma$-algebra. However, there are Borel sets of $X$ that are not meagre or co-meagre, for example the unit ball of $X$. Explicitly, if it was meagre then we could write it as an countable increasing union of nowhere dense subsets, and by scaling these sets we could in the end write $X$ as a countable union of nowhere dense sets, which contradicts Baire’s Category Theorem (for similar reasons the unit ball of X isn’t co-meagre either).

UPDATE: for a solution that doesn’t refer to nowhere denseness, note that
$$\mathcal{A}=\{A: A\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty C_n\text{ for some compact sets }C_n\}\cup \{A: X\backslash A\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty C_n\text{ for some compact sets }C_n\} $$

is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ that contains the compacts so it is enough to see that $\mathcal{A}$ does not contain the unit ball $B$ of $X$. Indeed, for any sequence of compacts $\{C_n\}$ Arzelà–Ascoli’s implies that there is a $\delta_n>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<1/n$ whenever $f\in C_n$ and $x, y\in [0, 1]$ satisfy $|x-y|<\delta_n$. However we can define a function $g$ that is $0$ at $0$ and $1$ at the points $\sum\limits_{n=1}^k \min(\delta_n, 2^{-n})$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$, and is $1/k$ at the «midpoints» $[\sum\limits_{n=1}^k \min(\delta_n, 2^{-n})]-\min(\delta_k, 2^{-k})/2$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$, and defined by linear interpolation elsewhere. Then $g\in B$ but $g\notin C_n$ for any $n$ so that $B\not\subseteq\bigcup\limits C_n$. Similarly, since $X\backslash B$ contains proper balls, it cannot be the contained in a countable union of compacts either. Hence $B\notin \mathcal{A}$.

Comment: Borel sunsets are something very poetic

Comment: I'm sorry but can you explain it without using the term meagre? We didn't have it in our courses. Thanks for helping.